# How to do encryption for a simple telephone on Nexus 5 and Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a Nexus 5 mobile phone and I installed Ubuntu Touch on it (based on Ubuntu 15). I want to encrypt voice out of the device when I use the phone application. Is that possible and how?

Comment: Connections on 3G and 4G networks are encrypted by default between tower and phone. Do you want encryption from phone to phone? If so, you'd have to use an app that supports encrypted calls.

Comment: yes i want a phone to phone encryption. Is there any free application to do that?

Comment: Favour returned!  Question upvoted!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible: the standard phone application uses 25-year-old technology with very low bandwidth and is just not suited to do encryption.  (9600 BAUD is just too little to add encryption)

#### Sorry!  :-(

<sub>**Having said that:** nothing is *truly impossible*, but to apply modern cryptographic encryption to a system that has such a low bandwidth would take a lot of processing power from the phone itself so that no one has bothered doing this: there are other ways of making encrypted calls out there...</sub>

Comment: The Telus network, among others, offers higher bandwidth for voice. What's the minimum required for encryption?

Comment: To clarify, my question is what's the minimum bandwidth needed to have an encrypted phone call with negligible latency?

Comment: No, I'm asking for clarification on your answer. You're saying the bandwidth is too low (because it's below a certain threshold). I'm asking what the threshold is. I'll put the question another way: how do you know 9600 baud is to low?

Comment: Fabby, you said there are other ways to make encrypted calls. what are they?

Comment: @ali Now that would be an entirely *[different question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)*.  As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If one of the answers solved your problem, don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is the most useful of all](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) ;-)

Comment: @Fabby, you said it is possible but with lots of processing power! how it is possible? it does not matter the solution takes much CPU cycles or the quality of voice is not good. Please tell me how encrypted voice is possible under any circumstances

Comment: Not under Ubuntu: you could install Android and run csipsimple